Firebase default code is not working for next.js
I am using Firebase for Next.js project but the default code provided by firebase is not working, its's showing "Failed to fetch inventory. Please try again."
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: " ",
  authDomain: " ",
  projectId: " ",
  storageBucket: " ",
  messagingSenderId: " ",
  appId: " ",
  measurementId: " "
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);


you initialized firebase but did not export it

import getFirestore
// Initialize Firestore and export it
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export { firestore, analytics };

code:
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: " ",
  projectId: " ",
  storageBucket: " ",
  messagingSenderId: " ",
  appId: " ",
  measurementId: " "
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

// Initialize Firestore and export it
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export { firestore, analytics };

